# Barker code autocorrelation

Tags: signal, dsp, processing, code

How do you auto correlate the following Barker code? I tried to use the formula on Wikipedia's page but it did not make sense to me.

+1, +1, -1, +1

Answer (score 1):

Correlating a signal with itself is often called an "optimal filter". It is the best possible filter for detecting the signal. I am not up on all the tricks of encoding data for WiFi, but I think all you need to do is multiply your input string of data by your filter string (+1 +1 -1 +1) in hunks of 4 datums and add up the results. You will get a maximum when your filter lines up with the signal you want. The result is 4 isn't it? Any other sequence will be less. The Barker codes are chosen to produce the lowest possible values when the correlation fails - the sequences do not line up.

If this is not just an exercise, then it gets more complicated.

Comment: I wrote an answer myself to this. It's not auto-correlation but it is an explanation of a  correlation using a shared pseudo-random bit stream.http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/99878/17273

Comment: This reminds me of early group code encoding for disc drives, like the ones invented by Wozniak. Lots of encoding bits (chips) per data bit. I didn't mention FFT  for correlation because it looks like it isn't needed and could introduce side band noise. I'll have to check.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "hunks of 4", but autocorrelation is much like a convolution, except you don't reverse the signal in time.  Slide, multiply, add; slide, multiply, add; etc.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Hunks of 4 was not the best way to say it. Multiply the filter (Barker code) by sequences of 4 input  bits and sum, then advance by one bit and repeat. A numerical correlation.